# PDO Prepared Statements: having trouble binding multiple values to query

Tags: php, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am new to PDO and prepared statements and I am having trouble binding multiple values to my query. I have no problem if it is just one while making a SELECT, for example:

```
SELECT foo FROM table WHERE id=:something // no problem
```

But multiple, and trying to INSERT I am getting stuck:

```
Insert INTO mytable (field1, field2) VALUES (:value1, :value2) // No bueno
```

Have tried a few different ways and read other posts on here but no luck. Below is an example of what I am having trouble with:

```
$insertSQL = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO voting_poll (ipaddress, choice) 
    VALUES (':ipaddress', :value)");
    $insertSQL->bindParam(':ipaddress', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insertSQL->bindParam(':value', $_POST['radio'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $insertSQL->execute();
```

I am getting the following error: **Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't put quotes around params. Remove the quotes around `:ipaddress` in your query.
2. [`bindParam()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) must be used with a variable as it binds the parameter to the variable reference. If you want to use a value (for example, the return value from a function like `getenv()`), use [`bindValue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) instead.

Comment: Thanks! I am glad that was easier that I thought. And thanks for the added info, Not sure why I changed here in the post but originally I had passed in a variable for the ip instead and that worked fine with the script, thanks for the heads up on bindValue()